# Who runs the healthcheck? Compose or the container itself?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Docker Compose stack running on an Amazon EC2 instance, and I am just now learning you can have a health check directly inside a Dockerfile, so I want to add it to one of my images like this example I saw:

```
HEALTHCHECK CMD curl --fail http://localhost:8080/health || exit 1
```

Who actually runs the `curl` command to see if the service is up? Is it:

1. Docker Compose running the curl command from outside the container; or
2. the container itself, i.e. curl command runs *inside* the container?

If it is 1, should this not be `http://<service-name>:8080/health` instead? Is it better to use `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` or `service-name` in a Dockerfile like this? is there a convention?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck

Comment: None of the above: the docker daemon is responsible for running the `curl` command, **inside the container**.

Comment: @larsks - oh wow. That kind of makes sense but... at the risk of asking an even more stupid question, why doesn't daemon run it from _outside_ the container?
Actually... wait, nm. I guess there'd be no way of guaranteeing it has the tools to run the test, because it can't know what the test involves? That must be it. Thx!

Comment: Right, you can't make assumptions about what tools will be available on the host, and additionally the test may depend on things (files, or particular software versions, etc) that are only available inside the container. E.g., what if your healthcheck was something like `test -f /tmp/flagfile`? Running that on the host, outside of the container, would be complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Dockerfiles provides a way to perform docker container health check as well as docker compose which allows to set healthcheck for the services that compose the application from the `docker-compose.yml` file, starting from version 2.1.

In both cases, from Dockerfiles or docker compose, the health checks are performed by the Docker daemon which invokes this command every 30 seconds and it determines if a container is healthy.

In particular, the healthcheck result is displayed in the STATUS column of the `docker ps` command and may have the results:

- 0 healthy container
- 1 unhealthy container

Please, refer to the official documentation https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck.